# How to set a baud rate to 10400

Tags: .net, serial-port, communication, baud-rate

Is it possible to set the baud rate to 10400? (Using .Net)

Comment: With the right hardware and device driver, yes, no problem.  The standard Windows device driver will flip you the bird.

Comment: @EFraim: What else can you set the *baud rate* of (as such) in a typical .Net environment than a serial port?

Comment: @Bandi-T: Of whatever. See the definition of baud rate. Serial ports are also not born equal. Some of them are implemented by user-space drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you examined the .NET SerialPort class [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) - the baud rate is one of the constructor arguments.

That said, the standard baud rates are generally considered to be:

*110, 300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 38400, 56000, 57600 &  115200*

...so your serial hardware many not support the somewhat curious rate you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this. Trust me. Even if you think you do, you don't.

Comment: A little more context would be nice for those of us who are curious... =)

Comment: Google search for 10400 baud results in links to documents mentioning OBD-II, the protocol to communicate with embedded computers in cars.

See for example this link: http://www.andywhittaker.com/ECU/OBDIISoftware/tabid/69/language/en-GB/Default.aspx

Comment: Good job entering this into Google. But I'll beat you with 20 years experience fiddling with all sorts of serial circuitry: You need a port chip that groks the weird baud rate. Which means that normal FIFOs in roundabout 100% of all .NET PCs won't be able to serve the baud rate. So you need an adaptor. And I guarantee you this converter will work with any off-the-shelf serial chip (or emulate the same using USB).

Comment: Hence you were right in the first place - I just provided references in response to Erik Forbes. (Sorry I did not make it clear that my reply was not directed at you.)

Answer (score 1):

A *baud rate* of a standard RS-232 UART can be set only at values which are divisors of 115200.
115200 does not divide by 10400. The closest divisor is 11, which will give you ~10472.72727272 baud.
You can set this rate by issuing a direct [IOCTL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546672%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to the serial port.

Answer (score -1):

The direct answer is Yes.  If you are implying another question (will it work?) I think you need to try it and see.

```
Dim mySP As New IO.Ports.SerialPort
mySP.BaudRate = 10400
```